# Deviations from the traditional form of correspondence

Tags: politeness, letter

This may be strictly off-topic, but I'm hoping it will pass.

If you receive a letter that does not begin with an adjectival phrase followed
by your name and end with herzlichst, hochachtungsvoll, beste gruesze, or some such phrase,
(1) how if at all offended are you, and (2) how do you reply?

PS. 
Maybe this never happens in German speaking countries.  But, if you were
to get a /letter/ (in all but the said features of its form) which it would
be impractical to ignore, what would you do?  Would you reply in the same form or politely as you would normally?

The background for my asking is that I live in a Scandinavian country, where the
traditional letter form is exactly the same as in German speaking countries.
But that form is now being suppressed by letters beginning with a single line
containing only the word 'hi'.  This will happen when you deal with a store or
your university &c.  To me this is deeply offensive, and I imagine it would be
to German speakers as well, but perhaps you never see it.

Take for example this e-mail from a printshop:

```
Hallo,

Soll der Umschlag rot oder grün sein?
```

Suppose, if it makes a difference, that this is in reply to a correct
letter.

PS II.
I use 'letter' to refer to electric as well as paper letters.

Comment: I think, in general this is a valid question for the site, however, it is too broad in its current state. Please narrow it down a little bit

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example please? Makes the question easier to digest!

Comment: Are these "letters" letters on paper or e-mails?

Comment: @IQV, both. I suppose I should have made that clear, but I tend to think of them as the same in different media.

Comment: The thing that would bug me is the uppercase *S*.

Answer (score 6):

I am not at all offended because such a letter is clearly a **Postwurfsendung** which means I'm expected to throw it away without taking further notice. Naturally, I don't reply.

Kidding aside, letters, also emails should begin at least with *Hallo ‹myname›* and more important, end with *Gruß, ‹yourname›*. Anything less is not a letter.

And *Hochachtungsvoll* is the equivalent of *Your unfriendly bureaucrat of cubicle 137*.

Comment: Right. If it really wants to be a letter, it must be embraced by forms of *hello* and *good bye*. If not, it's not a letter. I would not be offended by receiving such a piece of paper, but I probably would throw it away without reading, because I would not think that it really is important for me. Also correct: »*Hochachtungsvoll*« is an absolutely outdated no-go. Use »*Mit freundlichen Grüßen*« instead.

Comment: The intended premiss of the question is that this /is/ a letter to which you are expected to reply.  Imagine it would be impractiacal not to reply.

Comment: How come if the sender doesn't even know my name? Or how to greet? I rarely deal with such persons but it had yet to happen it was impractical to ignore them.

Comment: I have never understood what is so unacceptable about hochachtungsvoll.  It is polite; I don't think it has to be friendly.  Mit freundlichem Grusz, I think, is very unfriendly, much worse than hav.

Comment: @Toothrot In my opinion "Hochachtungsvoll" is very old-fashioned. "Mit freundlichen Grüßen" is the standard greeting at the end of a letter.

Comment: @iqv, it is exactly because it is the standard that it fails to be what it
purports to be.  If dealing with someone to whom one wishes to be friendly, and
not just polite, I think one should at least afford him a mit herzlichem grusz.
If one does not want to do that, I think hav. is more appropriate.

Comment: It's all about the people who write that. Only bureaucrats write *Hochachtungsvoll* nowadays and the letter on top of that is favorable only on very seldom occasions. *Liebe Grüße* is written by friends and relatives and *Mit freundlichen Grüßen* is written by anyone else.

Comment: I understand the connotation, but sometimes one does not want to be friendly, sometimes one is content to be polite.  Perhaps beste gruesze is also good for this purpose.  Perhaps hochachtungsvoll is also most of the time unfriendly; but that is not = impolite.  In any case, I for my part think denotation, at least in this case, is more important than connotation.